# How to ask for user input when running ruby code on remote server with capistrano?

Tags: io, capistrano, capistrano3

I want to confirm the action when running a capistrano task on a remote server:

```
task :do_someting do
  on roles(:primary) do
    within release_path do
      with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
        execute :rails, :runner,
          %Q['require "do_something"; Do::Something.()']
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Where `DoSomethig looks like this:

```
require "highline/import"

class DoSomething

  def self.call
    query_db_for_objects.each do |obj|
      answer = ask "Are you sure to do something with #{obj}? (y/n)"
      rerun unless answer == 'y'
      do_something
    end
  end

end
```

Method `ask` from highline gem doesn't seem to work when asking from a remote server and the command `bundle exec cap production do_something` hangs forever.

How can I ask for a user input from a remote server when running this capistrano task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to read the user answer from a remote server with the following ruby code

```
task :do_someting do

  class ConfirmHandler
    def on_data(command, stream_name, data, channel)
      if data.to_s =~ /\?$/
        prompt = Net::SSH::Prompt.default.start(type: 'confirm')
        response = prompt.ask "Please enter your response (y/n)"
        channel.send_data "#{response}\n"
      end
    end
  end

  on roles(:primary) do
    within release_path do
      with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
        execute :rails, :runner,
          %Q['require "do_something"; Do::Something.()']
      end
    end
  end

end
```

where `Do::Something` has `ask_user` method which looks the following way:

```
class Do::Something

  def self.call
    answer = ask_user
    puts "Answer is: #{answer}"
  end

  def self.ask_user
    puts 'Do something?'
    `read response; echo $response`
  end

end
```